# DropdownButton value is not updating after selecting values from DropdownItems. How to update default value with selectedValue?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dropdownbutton, stream-builder

```
DropdownButton Value does not update even after selecting different items.
```

If default value is null then error message is shown and if I pass any default value (not null) then it never changes to other selected values.

currentCategory is set as default value for DropdownButton.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: Firestore.instance
                        .collection('categories')
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      currentCategory = snapshot.data.documents[0];
                      return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child:
                            new DropdownButtonFormField<DocumentSnapshot>(
                          value: currentCategory,
                          onChanged: (DocumentSnapshot newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              currentCategory = newValue;
                            });
                            print(currentCategory.data['name']);
                          },
                          onSaved: (DocumentSnapshot newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              currentCategory = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: snapshot.data.documents
                              .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                            return new DropdownMenuItem<DocumentSnapshot>(
                              value: document,
                              child: Text(
                                document.data['name'],
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
```

help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: override `initState()`  and create a `stream` variable then set stream value in stream builder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Triggering [setState](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) will schedule a new [build](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/build.html) (the `build` method is always called after receiving a call to `setState`).

So I suggest you to move your query outside your widget and initialize the stream in a `initState` statement so that it is not computed every time the state change (unless you really need it).

Also move your `currentCategory` outside the widget `build` method.

Something like this should work :

```
class YourClass extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}

class _YourClassState extends State<YourClass> {

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _categories;
  DocumentSnapshot _currentCategory;

  initState() {
    _categories = Firestore.instance.collection('categories').snapshots();
    return super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _categories,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: new DropdownButtonFormField<DocumentSnapshot>(
              value: _currentCategory,
              onChanged: (DocumentSnapshot newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentCategory = newValue;
                });
              }
            )
          )
        }
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Also note that `setState` only work for stateful widgets.

Comment: Had a problem exactly like him, using FutureBuilder to populate my dropdown menu but it didnt work. Your solution gave me a good hit in the right direction altough i have to say some things just go easier with stream/future builder

Comment: I have this issue too

Answer (score 0):

That's because everytime you do a `setState` even though the `currentCategory` changed, it will rebuild your tree and go through `currentCategory = snapshot.data.documents[0];` back again giving you the idea that is not being set.

Replace it by `if(currentCategory == null) currentCategory = snapshot.data.documents[0];` so it will be set only if this condition is met.

Comment: This error message is displayed now if I set initialvalue if it is equal to null.           
    The following assertion was thrown building DropdownButtonFormField<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _DropdownButtonFormFieldState<DocumentSnapshot>#b9cd7): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 514 pos 15: 'items == null || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == value).length == 1': is not true.