# DropdownButton value is not updating after selecting values from DropdownItems. How to update default value with selectedLocation?

Tags: flutter, dart

DropdownButton value is not updating after selecting values from DropdownItems. How to update default value with _selectedLocation?
The variables i use:

```
  String? stateToCountry;
  List? stateID;
  List? cityJson;
  Position? _position;
  String? currentAddress;
  Placemark? place;
```

```
    DropdownButton(
               hint:_selectedLocation==null ? Text('Dropdown') : Text(
                 _selectedLocation.toString(),
                 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
               ),
              isExpanded: true,
              iconSize: 30,
              elevation: 16,
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple, fontSize: 20.0),
              itemHeight: 50,
              items: countrylist!.map((location){
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: location,
                  child: new Text(location["name"].toString()),

                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (newValue){
                 setState(() {
                   _selectedLocation=newValue as String?;
                 });
              },

                ),
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044747/dropdownbutton-value-is-not-updating-after-selecting-values-from-dropdownitems?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdownbutton works as follows:

`T` represent a generic type, so you can pass a bool, String, double, YourCustomModel etc.

The Dropdownbutton needs 3 things:

- The value `T`
- A `List<T>` with the options,
- The `onChanged` Function, which pass you the `T` value you select.

The widget, know which value is selected according as his instance,
each object has an `hashCode` property which identify it from other objects,
When you select an option, you must keep that instance.

That instance should be in your list, for example

```dart
final list=<String>[
'Hello', /// hashCode 1
'good bye', /// hashCode 2
'bye bye' /// hashCode 3
];
```

When you select one, this is pass through the onChanged, let's say you select the first option:

```dart
onChanged:(value){
print(value.hashCode); /// output value: 1
// you must keep that instance with the same type `T`
_selectedValue=value;
}
```

So now, your `_selectedValue` will be:

```dart
print(_selectedValue.hashCode);/// /// output value: 1
print(_selectedValue); /// output value: 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value property,

```dart
DropdownButton(
  value: _selectedLocation,
  onChanged:(newValue){
      setState(() {
        _selectedLocation=newValue;
      });
  }
```

Comment: The problem remains the same.

Comment: Don't put it as String?

Comment: when i remove 'as String' i get another error.